# I'm trying to connect to a service that is on a remote server and can't make it work

Tags: java, android, request, connection

I have an app written in android studio 2.3.3 workspace for android 5 platform and now I am trying to run it in android studio 3.5.3 workspace

The could not connect to a service that it was able to connect to previously

Here is the function that calls the web service;

```
 private void syncManufacturers() {
        mSyncInfoTextView.setText(R.string.syncing_manufacturers);
        WebService.getInstance(this).getAllManufacturers(new ServerResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            protected void onServerResponseSuccess(Object object) {

                ArrayList<ManufacturerRemoteModel> allManufacturerLocalModelArrayList = (ArrayList<ManufacturerRemoteModel>) object;
                try {
                    // Store all manufacturers in preferences.
                    if (allManufacturerLocalModelArrayList != null) {
                        PreferencesEditor.getInstance(ServerSyncActivity.this).putJSONableArrayList(C.PrefsKey.MANUFACTURERS_ALL, allManufacturerLocalModelArrayList);
                        // Manufacturers are synced successfully.
                        PreferencesEditor.getInstance(ServerSyncActivity.this).putBoolean(C.PrefsKey.SYNC_SUCCESS_MANUFACTURERS, true);
                        // If everything went fine so far, start sync for the next step.
                        syncTreatments();
                    } else {


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onServerResponseError(WebServiceError error) {
                onSyncFailedManufacturers();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: plz provide the details of the "WebService" it is android predefined api or  any third party api

Comment: Could you test your service in a browser? If you could do this please check responding of your service. Also you could debug from the first line of your method.Trace it line by line